# Regex pattern search in TextPad fails, works in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, textpad

I'm trying to use TextPad to search for a regular expression in several files. I have a simple pattern but it doesn't work in TextPad.  It works fine in Visual Studio.

Anyone have any ideas?

I'm searching for:

```
hosted.mysite.com or host.mysite.com
```

using the pattern:

```
(hosted|host)\.mysite\.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
 host\(ed\)?\.mysite\.com
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  The host names are actually two different words entirely though...should've used a different example :/

something like: somehost.mysite.com and bling.mysite.com

in my original post I did have escape slashes before my dots but they got stripped.

Comment: +1. Looking at http://www.textpad.com/support/tips/ it seems that many regex meta characters in TextPad need to be escaped in able to work properly. Odd. @OP, the above should work, and your own solution **should** work when you escape the logical OR as well: `\(hosted\|host\)\.mysite\.com` (untested!)

Comment: no dice.

and yes that is very weird that you'd need to escape the meta chars...shouldn't it look for them literally then?  Ohwell a topic for another time.  But regardless, your solution still isn't flying.  Any other ideas?

I found this resource: http://docs.google.com/gview?a=v&q=cache%3AIN-HNpeNlG8J%3Awww-user.uni-bremen.de%2F~anatol%2Fdocs%2Fcorp_regex.pdf+Textpad+regex&hl=en&gl=ca&sig=AFQjCNGrbwIzN6j88cay-uq47TAojnyX1w&pli=1

Comment: It seems TextPad does not support the optional `?` quantifier.

Comment: @Burrito: if you have the `Use POSIX regular expression syntax preference` set in the Editor preference panel, you shouldn't escape the parens.

Comment: ...don't escape the pipe in the use POSIX RE syntax case either.

Answer (score 5):

Use something like this

```
\(hosted\|host\).mysite.com
```

Comment: note:  if you have the Use POSIX regular expression syntax preference set in the Editor preference panel, you shouldn't escape the parens or the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Not every text editor uses the same regex/conventions. A regex you may get to work in Visual Studio won't necessarily work in Eclipse, Netbeans, or some other IDE or text editor.

Comment: I'd vote +1, but this doesn't answer the question, does it? :) Anyway, good comment.

Answer (score 1):

In Textpad you need to escape some characters, such as parenthesis and pipes.

In your case, what you need is this:

```
\(hosted\|host\)\.mysite\.com
```

**Note:** you need to escape dots as well.

Comment: No idea, dude. I tested this before posting and it works in my box :(

Answer (score 1):

Textpad's POSIX regexes are good, but even better results could be achieved by installing the Win GNU util grep and adding a cmd /c "Prompt for parameters " , "Capture output" command: thus you could have full Find in files with even Perl regexes: 
grep -nhPr "CoolRegexToSearchWith" C:\MyDir\ToSearchRecursivly